# How to avoid std::process::Command single quote escaping

Tags: rust, ffmpeg, command

I am trying to run an ffmpeg command with a complex filter in Rust, and the `std::process::Command` blocks me from executing it by escaping the singles quotes, required as is by ffmpeg.

```rust
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let mut cmd = Command::new("ffmpeg");
    cmd.args([
        "-filter_complex",
        "[video_0]geq=lum='p(X,Y)'[video_0];",
    ]);
    println!("Running command {:?}", cmd);
    // Actual:
    // Running command "ffmpeg" "-filter_complex" "[video_0]geq=lum=\'p(X,Y)\'[video_0];"
    // Expected: 
    // Running command "ffmpeg" "-filter_complex" "[video_0]geq=lum='p(X,Y)'[video_0];"

}
```

How can I run this command so that the single quotes are not escaped?
Is this a bug from the Command implementation?

Answer (score 1):

`Command`'s debug view just view the arguments in debug view and that includes escaping characters, but it will still work.

Comment: Obviously if I ask it's because it *doesn't* work, I've tried it a thousand times.

Comment: [Here's a simple playground showing it's spawning the command without the backslashes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7af515a77b08d04ffb310d696b8ad843). Make sure you're actually capturing the arguments `ffmpeg` got and not the debug view from the Rust side.

Comment: As described in the ffmpeg doc, https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#toc-Quoting-and-escaping, 
>  The quote character ‘'’ itself cannot be quoted, so you may need to close the quote and escape it.

Comment: @whisust What are you trying to say with that?

Comment: Ok, it looks like my command was adding an additional char, so I was wrong in the command building,and you were right.
Thank you